# Orange Pi registers pointers list needed

Tags: register

I need the orange Pi lite registers mapping for a project but I can't find it anywhere. Does someone know the mapping of the registers?

Comment: Does it have a data sheet?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer - this is one of the issues with the less well supported Linux SBCs.

Comment: @Andyaka no it does not have one

Comment: @Ivano  **cardinal rule:**  *No datasheet ⇒ No sale*

Comment: agreed, in general anything Alwinner you are not supposed to have access to the chip docs, but unlike broadcom, the Allwinner docs are sometimes leaked or outright distributed despite the watermarks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that one is based on the Allwinner H3 SoC. Presumably you have, or can find, a schematic for the PCB.

[Here](http://dl.linux-sunxi.org/H3/Allwinner_H3_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf) is a link to the 618-page datasheet for the SoC. For example, GPIO register locations are shown below:

[image]

Comment: thanks @Spehro Pefhany but I need some addictional registers apart from these. I have contacted the Orange Pi support and I will update this post as soon as I get an answer from them